# Getting "404 Page Not Found" in Codeigniter 2 after moving to the server contains php 5.2.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-2, php-5.2

My codeigniter 2 is working fine in PHP 5.3. But when it moves to server which contains version of PHP 5.2.1 i am getting

`404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.`

without any change in code.

Please help in this.

Thanks

Comment: go and check your page which is you loading your controller is the page is available. i think you miss the page to upload or you have permeation problem please add the url

Comment: @Yaseen thanks for the reply. I have just uploaded the file, what we get when we download. Didn't do any changes. But that same file is working in my localhost, not in the server

Comment: Then i think you have permeation problem check the file permeation if you able send the url i'll check

Comment: Check for the file name if it is in small letter.Change file name to First letter to Capital letter and then check it on server.

Comment: this sounds like a permission problem, try to echo smt on the top of index.php file in the project root

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file code.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the late update guys!!

its working now!!

Actual problem is in `.htaccess`. Its working fine when i update the `.htaccess` to

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase 'XXXXX'
```

and also created one `sessions` folder with proper permissions for session based errors.

Thanks all for the response